# Confused when delivering PrimaryKeyRelatedField to the Client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

If you extract the value of the field used as PrimaryKeyRelatedField, you will see the value in the form of Object, not PK.

In the case of the official document, I am using it as below, but it is confusing when using it with the client.

I don't know if the tracks will contain id or Object just by looking at the field name.

```py
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['tracks']
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
                tracks = validated_data.pop('tracks')  # [Track, Track ...]
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracks` in `tracks = validated_data.pop('tracks')` will contain `Track` objects, because you are getting it from `validated_data` which uses `to_internal_value` which in turn gives you the model instance objects.

You can have a look at `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`'s implementation here:

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L243

The implementation of `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` should give you hints. You can read more here:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior